# How to find file size in scala?

Tags: java, file, scala, size

I'm writing a scala script, that need to know a size of a file. How do I do this correctly?
In Python I would do

```
os.stat('somefile.txt').st_size
```

and in Scala?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no way to do this using the Scala standard libraries.  Without resorting to external libraries, you can use the Java [File.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)  method do do this.  In Scala, this would look like:

```
import java.io.File
val someFile = new File("somefile.txt")
val fileSize = someFile.length
```

If you want something Scala-specific, you can use an external framework like [scalax.io](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/overview) or [rapture.io](http://rapture.io/)

Comment: Thank you! Are there own Scala methods for that? Or to use Java method is the only way?

Comment: There are no standard ways to do this in the standard Scala release, but there are several external frameworks you could use.  I updated my answer with those.

Comment: `scala.reflect.io.Path.length`, but for some reason it doesn't throw on `isDirectory`, as the java API is undefined for dirs.  A `Directory` knows that it is one and could balk.

Answer (score 3):

**java.nio.file.Files.size**

from api:

*public static long size(Path path) throws IOException*

*Returns the size of a file (in bytes)*

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.File;
val file:File = new File("your file path");
file.length()
```