# how to get upcoming file size in KB

Tags: java, scala, playframework

how to get the size of video or audio file in KB in scala.
tried this but it doesnt help me
[How to find file size in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596515/how-to-find-file-size-in-scala)

`size` and `length` always returning 1.

```
def uploadVideo = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
      request.body.files.map { mov =>
            println(request.body.files.size) //returns 1
            println(request.body.files.length)//returns 1
      }
      Ok("success")
  }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the returned value `1` is the length/size of a List or array containing the uploaded files?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes i am thinking same, but I want something else :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly by some hit and try i got the solution

```
def uploadVideo = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
     request.body.files.map { mov =>
        println(mov.ref.file.length/1024)//exact in KB
     }
     Ok("success")
}
```